# I cannot able to validate the form using the above code in PHP (PHP FORM VALIDATION)

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I wanted to validate the form in PHP but it doesn't give any output from validate.php

this PHP code didn't give any output after submitting the Form 
help me with this form validation

> validate.php

```
    function validate($data, $reg_exp = "") {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      if (empty($data) == true) {
        $Err = "EMT_FLD";
        return false;
      } else{
        if ($reg_exp != "") {
          if (preg_match($reg_exp, $data) !== true) {
            $Err = "PRG_MTH_ERR";
            return false;
          } else {
             return true ;
            return $data;
          }
        }else {
          return true ;
          return $data;
        }
      }
    }
```

> register.php

```
      include 'validate.php';

          if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
              $fnErr = $lnErr = $unErr = $emErr = $psErr = $cpErr = "";
              $submit = false;

              if ($val = validate($_POST['firstname'],"/^['a-zA-Z']+$/")) {
                  if ($val == false) {
                    if($Err == "EMT_FLD"){
                      $fnErr = "<span class = 'error'>First Name Required</span>";
                    }
                    if($Err == "PRG_MTH_ERR") {
                      $fnErr = "<span class = 'error'>Invalid First Name, Only Letters Are Allowed (A-Z and a-z)</span>";
                    }
                  }elseif($val == true){
                    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                  }
              }
          }

     echo $fnErr."<br>";
```

Expected: It Should Return the `$fnErr`, But It Returns Nothing

Comment: Where did you `echo $fnErr`?

Comment: in register.php file

Comment: You need to show that file as well

Comment: In `validate.php` you use return twice. The 2nd one will never been executed as the first one stops execution of the function.

Answer (score 0):

you have some problem in your logic.

`return` stop the function execution. So your `validate` function always return a boolean and not your error code. You should return the error string and check if it's empty or not.

I propose that :

> validate.php

```
    function validate($data, $reg_exp = "") {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      if (empty($data) == true) {
        return  "EMT_FLD";
      } else{
        if ($reg_exp != "") {
          if (preg_match($reg_exp, $data) !== true) {
            return "PRG_MTH_ERR";
          } else {
             return '';
          }
        }else {
          return '';
        }
      }
    }
```

> register.php

```
      include 'validate.php';

          if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
              $fnErr = $lnErr = $unErr = $emErr = $psErr = $cpErr = "";
              $submit = false;

              if ($val = validate($_POST['firstname'],"/^['a-zA-Z']+$/")) {
                  if ($val !== '') {
                    if($val == "EMT_FLD"){
                      $fnErr = "<span class = 'error'>First Name Required</span>";
                    }
                    if($val == "PRG_MTH_ERR") {
                      $fnErr = "<span class = 'error'>Invalid First Name, Only Letters Are Allowed (A-Z and a-z)</span>";
                    }
                  }elseif($val === ''){
                    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                  }
              }
          }

     echo $fnErr."<br>";
```